# Как на python selenium максимально быстро проверить, что браузер не отвалился и жив?

Tags: python, selenium

Как на python selenium максимально быстро проверить, что браузер не отвалился и жив?

Есть приложение, где постоянно запущен браузер под селениумом. И иногда по непонятным причинам браузер (файрфокс) падает.

Хочется найти именно максимально быстрый способ проверки состояния браузера, чтобы его перезапустить.

Вариант в try / except блоке сделать тестовый `driver.get('http://ya.ru')` не хочется, так как в это время браузер будет занят. А логика работы приложения такова, что браузер должен максимально быстро реагировать на команды.

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool InstanceExist
    {
        get
        {
            if (Instance != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    return (Instance.WindowHandles != null); // allways returns true if browser instance exist or thrown error
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return false;
                    // means that browser was closed by user
                }
            }
            return false; // means that it wasn't created yet or was closed by developer programmally
        }
    }
```

Есть 3 ситуации которые нужно обработать:

1. драйвер не был инициализирован
2. драйвер закрыт девом
3. браузер был закрыт юзером или отвалился

Все эти ситуации покрываются кодом выше (на шарпе, но на питоне будет та же логика) инстанс -- и есть инстанс драйвера

Answer (score 0):

Во время старта selenium'а поднимается сервак на локалхосте (хоть и не обязательно), соответственно получение любой информации от браузера делится на несколько этапов:

1. Пробуем подключиться к драйверу
2. Если подключились, то отправляем запрос
3. Получаем ответ

Не знаю что означает "браузер падает" (упал интернет, процесс или что?)

Если отваливается все, то еще при подключении он будет ругаться, что не удалось подключиться (там хоть title вызывай, хоть get, будет рейзить ошибку)

Какую ошибку он выдает? На это надо ссылаться.